# targeting element within an element stored in a fragment

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to target the element I want in this case:

```
  var $div = $(".row-container").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("i") == product_id;
        // where value == product id to find
      });
```

Now, within `$div` is an element that has the class `'price-row'` which is what I want. `$div.hasClass('price-row')` only returns true or false value.

Comment: Could you please update your question to show some example html? I for one don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Your last sentence makes it sound like `$div` is set correctly via the existing `.filter()` method but now you want to find a child element? Or is the problem in how to get `.filter()` to do what you need? Where does the "fragment" concept come into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) if it's a child element:

```
var $div = $(".row-container").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("i") == product_id; // where value == product id to find
}).find('.price-row');
```

If you meant that the matching element will be within that set, include it in the criteria to begin with:

```
var $div = $(".row-container.price-row").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("i") == product_id; // where value == product id to find
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $(".row-container .price-row")? As in not connected seeing as it's a child?

Comment: @Joey: Nope. If it's a child element, it should be `find`. Or, at least, that's what I took the question to mean, specifically: *"Now, within $div is an element that has the class 'price-row' which is what I want."* So, either the element in the `$div` collection that has the class `price-row` (example 2) or a child of any element in the `$div` collection that has the class `price-row` (example 1).